# MUI Fade component does not show, hide, or fade components

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I switched child components from conditional rendering to being wrapped by `<Fade />` but Fade doesn't work at all, both components always display. Here is the current code:

```
// inside top level component
{/*{adminView === bodyViews.addNewCoupon &&*/}
<Fade
  in={Boolean(adminView === bodyViews.addNewCoupon)}
  timeout={2000}
>
  <AddCouponForm />
</Fade>
{/*}*/}
  
{/*{adminView === bodyViews.viewCurrentCoupons &&*/}
<Fade
  in={Boolean(adminView === bodyViews.viewCurrentCoupons)}
  timeout={2000}
>
  <ViewCoupons />
</Fade>
{/*}*/}
```

Based on the API [here](https://mui.com/api/fade). I believe `in` set to true should cause the component to fade in. This worked for causing a conditional render in the commented out unary but does not seem to work within the `in` value. What mistake is being made?

**Update**

When I comment the custom components and inserting something like `<p>Section 1/2</p>` then the fade works. Something about the custom compoonents must cause the fade not to work

Comment: Please provide a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) that reproduces your problem.

Comment: Ok, I have done so. The problem is, it works! https://codesandbox.io/embed/material-ui-fade-g2p7z

I will need to test this further to isolate the true issue myself. Thank you regardless

Answer (score 29):

The issue was traced specifically back to Custom components: they don't seem to work as direct children of `<Fade />`. Issue is solved by wrapping the custom component children in a div.

```
  <Fade
    in={ Boolean(adminView === bodyViews.addNewCoupon) }
    timeout={ 4000 }
  >
    <div>
      <AddCouponForm />
    </div>
  </Fade>     

  <Fade
    in={ Boolean(adminView === bodyViews.viewCurrentCoupons) }
    timeout={ 4000 }
  >
    <div>
      <p>Section 2</p>
      <ViewCoupons />
    </div>
  </Fade>
```

As a side note, Fade also seems to have issues with more than one child. Therefore all children should go inside a single div element.

Comment: It is fine to use custom components, but Fade passes props to your component that you need to pass through to whatever HTML element is the top-level element within your component. Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-fade-56gpi

Comment: wrapping div around element worked ✅

Comment: Additional to what @RyanCogswell pointed out, refer to the documentation on the child requirements https://mui.com/material-ui/transitions/#child-requirement .

Answer (score 7):

`Fade` updates the child component via the `styles` prop, if you're using a custom component you need to forward the ref to the child and make sure the `props` from `Fade` are passed down:

```
const MyComponent = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  return (
    <div {...props} ref={ref}>
      my component
    </div>
  );
});
```

```
<Fade in={checked}>
  <MyComponent />
</Fade>
```

### Live Demo

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Comment: Thank you for this. I was pulling my hair trying to get Fade to work with my custom components using forwardRef. Just needed to forward the style prop and everything worked.